# GoogleMaps Intent without starting navigation

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this code:

```
botonruta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri urimap= Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+oficina.latitude+","+oficina.longitude);
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, urimap);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
    });
```

This way, when the button is clicked, GoogleMaps starts navigation. I want it to wait for the user to hit "start navigation" once the Google Maps app is started.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

EDIT

Solved:

Did it this way:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=" + source.getLatitude() + "," + source.getLongitude() + "&daddr=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;
Uri urimap = Uri.parse(uri);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, urimap);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Comment: Then don't start navigation, just start the map with directions between places. there will be an option to start navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to construct the uri like this:

```
Uri urimap= Uri.parse("geo:"+oficina.latitude+","+oficina.longitude);
```

with the "`geo:`" prefix insted of "`google.navigation:q=`"

Comment: Trying now, I will give feedback soon.

Comment: It takes my location, but does not displays the location I want.

Comment: which location does it display? :/

Comment: Only the location of my device

Comment: if you fix a random lat long it also show your location?

Comment: maybe post your code again. or try to print the oficina lat long and check if it makes sense :/

Comment: In fact, the LatLng I am sending is 400km away from here, and it shows my location. The LatLng is ok because if I start the Intent, the route shown is the expected.